# Add NSTableView To SpriteKit app

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview

I finally created a `NSTableView` programmatically. I added an `NSScrollView` to it, but for some reason it doesn't show the scroll. If I add more and more objects to the table it grows in height and I want it to remain the same height. How can this be done? Here's the code below that I've cobbled together.

```
#import "GameScene.h"

@interface GameScene()

@property NSMutableArray *data;

@end

@implementation GameScene 

- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    _data = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", @"8", nil];

    NSRect rect = NSMakeRect(300, 200, 400, 100);
    _tableView = [[NSTableView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    [_tableView addTableColumn:[[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"column 1"]];
    _tableView.dataSource = self;
    _tableView.delegate = self;

    NSScrollView *scrollView = [[NSScrollView alloc] init];
    [scrollView setHasVerticalScroller:YES];
    [scrollView setDocumentView:self.tableView];

    [self.view addSubview:_tableView];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
    return [_data count];
}

-(NSView*)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    NSTextView *textView = [[NSTextView alloc] init];
    textView.string = [_data objectAtIndex:row];
    return textView;
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    // Called before each frame is rendered
}

-(void)removeUIViews{
    [_tableView removeFromSuperview];
}

@end
```

Here's what it looks like with 8 elements in the data array:

[image]

Here's what it looks like with 16 elements in the data array (taller table):

[image]

Comment: It's not good idea to add UI objects to SKScene. It is better to customize your own table/scrollview using spritekit 100%. I think you will face performance problem later on.

Comment: So basically you're saying that I should subclass NSTableView? I was reading in another SO post that it's better not to subclass a table.

Comment: Sorry @GeneCode, I'm an idiot. I misread what you wrote like 10 times in a row. I know what you're saying now. I'll create my own table class. It probably won't be as robust and will take longer, but the performance gains will be worth it. Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah. But you can also search for 3rd party spritekit table if you want to save time. I havent search it but i believe someone might have made one.

Comment: That's actually what I'm looking for now. I just realized that getting scrolling to work well could be difficult and take some time. I'll look around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[self.view addSubview:_tableView];` moves the table view from the scrollview/clipview to `self.view`.

`[self.view addSubview:scrollView];` adds the scroll view with the table view to `self.view`.

Comment: I just switched `[self.view addSubview:_tableView];` to `[self.view addSubview:scrollView];` and now I don't see anything :(

Comment: I fixed it...I forgot to initialized the `NSScrollView` with init instead of iniWithFrame:

Thanks for the help.